# python3 : How to remove data inbetween two parameters of Mediawiki template

Tags: python-3.x, python-re, mediawiki-templates, pywikibot

**The following is the data from a Wikisource page;-**

```
{{:MediaWiki:Proofreadpage_index_template
|Type=book
|Title=மணி பல்லவம் 1
|Language=ta
|Author=நா. பார்த்தசாரதி
|Translator=
|Illustrator=
|Editor=
|Volumes=5
|School=
|Publisher=தமிழ்ப் புத்தகாலயம்
|Address=சென்னை
|Year=ஏழாம் பதிப்பு 2000
|Source=pdf
|Image=1
|Number of pages=295
|File size=19.88
|Category=
|Progress=C
|Pages=<pagelist 
1=நூலட்டை
2= உரிமம்
4=பதிப்பு
|Remarks=மேம்படுத்திய உள்ளடக்கத்தரவு

1. இந்திர விழா 12

2. சக்கரவாளக் கோட்டம் 22

3. கதக்கண்ணன் வஞ்சினம் 26

|Width=
|Css=
|Header=
|Footer=
|Key=
|ISBN=
|OCLC=
|LCCN=
|BNF_ARK=
|ARC=
}}
```

I want to delete few specific data in between two parameters i.e., start from *|Remarks=*  and *|Width=*. I tried by the following code but it deletes all the data after the parameter"|Remarks=" instead of i mentioned as above. How can i delete the data only in between the above said parameters?

**My test code;-**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random, csv, time, subprocess, re, pywikibot

wikiPage1 = 'அட்டவணை:மணி பல்லவம் 1.pdf'
site = pywikibot.Site('ta', 'wikisource')
page1 = pywikibot.Page(site, wikiPage1)

res1 =  re.sub(r'\|Remarks= *.*(?s)', '|Remarks=' , page1.text)

print(res1)
```

Comment: the comment is useful but it has been deleted. Why? Sorry i forget the commentor's name. the result is positive https://ta.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%9F%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A3%E0%AF%88:%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%A3%E0%AE%BF_%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B2%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D_1.pdf&curid=236914&diff=1148876&oldid=1148705

Answer (score 0):

The comment is useful.when i clicked the useful comment is removed. why? Anyhow **my recode** is as follows;-
The wiki page result is positive as needed. It going to help morethan 2000 books creation.Many thanks, brother. sorry i forget your name, excuse me.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random, csv, time, subprocess, re, pywikibot
    
அட்டவணைப்பெயர் = 'அட்டவணை:மணி பல்லவம் 1.pdf'

site = pywikibot.Site('ta', 'wikisource')
page1 = pywikibot.Page(site, அட்டவணைப்பெயர்)


with open('0trans-தற்போதுள்ளநடுப்பகுதிவார்ப்புருஇப்ப26-கோப்பு.csv') as இடுகோப்பு3:
    இடுகோப்புத்தரவு3 = இடுகோப்பு3.read()
    #print(இடுகோப்புத்தரவு3)
    
#res1 =  re.sub(r'\|Remarks= *.*(?s)', '|Remarks=' , page1.text)
    page1.text = re.sub(r'(?<=\|Remarks=)[\s\S]*?(?=\|Width=)', '\n' + இடுகோப்புத்தரவு3 + '\n', page1.text)
    
    print(page1.text)
    
    page1.save(summary='+ உள்ளடக்கத்தரவில் வார்ப்புருக்கள் இடப்பட்டன')
```

Comment: https://github.com/neqkir/wikisource-scraper